# Discrete heat map with GNUPLOT

Tags: gnuplot

I'm trying to make something as a heat map with GNUPLOT but I need that my palette takes discrete colors for defined values.

I mean, my data file has three columns, for example:

x    y     value

---

0.0    0.0    10
0.0    0.5    2
0.0    1.0    2
0.5    1.0    10
1.0    0.0    -1
1.0    1.0    -1

I need that each point has one color depending of its value. Traditional heat map mixes point making regions of continuos colors, but I need it in a discrete form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data forms a "matrix", i.e., there are M x-samples, N y-samples, and you have the data for all MxN points, then probably the easiest solution is to use

```
plot ... w rgbimage u 1:2:(r($3)):(g($3)):(b($3))
```

and supply the r,g,b values as three additional columns as shown above.

However, if your data is "sparse" (only some of the samples are available as shown in your question) and there are not many points, one might be tempted to generate the elementary squares forming the plot manually. To this end, one could proceed as:

```
set terminal png enhanced
set output 'plot.png'

#custom value -> color mapping
rgb(r, g, b) = 65536 * int(r) + 256 * int(g) + int(b)
fn(val) = rgb(100 + val*10, 0, 0)

#square size
delta = 0.5
set xr [-delta/2:1+delta/2]
set yr [-delta/2:1+delta/2]

set xtics 0,delta/2,1 out nomirror
set ytics 0,delta/2,1 out nomirror

set format x "%.2f"
set format y "%.2f"

set size ratio 1

unset key

fName="test.dat"

load sprintf("<gawk -v d=%f -f parse.awk %s", delta, fName)
plot fName u 1:2:3 w labels tc rgb 'white'
```

This script assumes the presence of auxiliary gawk script `parse.awk` in the same directory:

```
{
    printf "set object rectangle from %f,%f to %f,%f fc rgb fn(%d) fs solid\n",
        $1-d/2, $2-d/2, $1+d/2, $2+d/2, $3
}
```

This scripts accepts the required square size (`-v d=%f` in the invocation of gawk) and generates for each point a statement generating the corresponding square. These statements are consequently executed by the `load` command.

Mapping of the colors is done via the function `fn` defined in the main Gnuplot script. It takes the passed value and generates a rgb value which is then used with `fc rgb` in the `rectangle` specification.

Together, this then produces:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

This might do what you want, after some fiddling:

`set view map
set style fill transparent solid noborder
splot 'data' u 1:2:3:(100+200*$3) pt 5 lc rgbcolor var ps 14`

The `pt 5` will plot a square (at least in the x11 term) at each point in the datafile, colored according to a transformation on the last column.